How to create a partition in a disk using cloud-init
I am using cloud-init to setup an instance in oracle cloud.
I have the following yaml to create a partition on a drive, format it for ext4 and mount it.
#cloud-config
disk_setup:
  /dev/sdb: {layout: true, overwrite: true, table_type: gpt}
fs_setup:
  - device: /dev/sdb
  - filesystem: ext4
  - label: data
  - partition: auto
mounts:
  - [ /dev/sdb1, /scratch ]

However, this is not creating the partition that I expect should be created in fs_setup
# fdisk -l
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sda: 50.0 GB, 50010783744 bytes, 97677312 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 1048576 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: AEAC51C9-5D28-48CB-82FF-1B7312827FEB


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       411647    200M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 2       411648     17188863      8G  Linux swap      
 3     17188864     97675263   38.4G  Microsoft basic 

Disk /dev/sdb: 549.8 GB, 549755813888 bytes, 1073741824 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 1048576 bytes

I dont see any errors in cloud-init.log or in /var/log/messages
My version of cloud-init is
# cloud-init --version
/bin/cloud-init 19.4

Here is the effective cloud-init file from /var/lib/cloud/instance/cloud-config.txt
#cloud-config

# from 2 files
# fdisk.yaml
# cloud-init.yaml

---
disk_setup:
    /dev/sdb:
        layout: true
        overwrite: true
        table_type: gpt
fs_setup:
-   device: /dev/sdb
-   filesystem: ext4
-   label: data
-   partition: auto
mounts:
-   - /dev/sdb1
    - /scratch
runcmd:
- chown "fdaud:root" /scratch
users:
-   gecos: Feroze Daud
    groups: sudo
    homedir: /home/fdaud
    name: fdaud
    shell: /bin/bash
    ssh_authorized_keys:
    - ssh-ed25519 REDACTED
    sudo:
    - ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
...

If I run the disk_setup section manually using cloud-int, it works fine.
any ideas what I am doing wrong?

I found the problem. The disk_setup key was disabled in the cloud-config file /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.
I dont understand this. The docs for cloud-init v 19.4 say that disk_setup/fs_setup are available. But the examples for this version has the following comment:
# (Not implemented yet, but provided for future documentation)

Anyway, looks like this doesnt work with cloud-init v 19.4. So I changed it to run commands in the runcmd
